# Get value of TD where Checkbox is checked in table

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code, im trying to get the value of each TD with id=tel2 and checkbox is checked and store all values in textarea separated with Comma ','
Any suggestion ?

```
                echo "<div>";

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {


                    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>"; 

                    echo "<tr> <th></th> <th>Nom</th> <th>Prenom</th> <th>Tel</th> <th>Classe</th> <th>Annee</th> </tr>";

                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "<tr>";

                        echo "<td> <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"case\"></td>";

                        echo "<td>" . $row['nom'] . "</td>";

                        echo "<td>" . $row['prenom'] . "</td>";

                        echo "<td id=\"tel2\">" . $row['tel'] . "</td>";

                        echo "<td>" . $row['classe'] . "</td>";

                        echo "<td>" . $row['annee'] . "</td>";

                        echo "</tr>";
                    }

                        echo "</table>";
                }

                echo "</div>";

                ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what issues have you encountered?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Also, where's the JavaScript that you tried? We don't need to see the PHP either, just the rendered HTML and your JavaScript.